# Can I pursue a PhD in the Netherlands with no Masters?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, netherlands

I'm a 37-year-old student with 12 years professional experience in the field of the PhD and a strong BA (Hons) in the academic field of the project. Linguistic fluency in the indigenous languages and 1 peer-reviewed academic paper. I'm wondering if I can apply for a PhD in the Netherlands with this profile?

I have direct field research experience in the project area and I'm currently working as a research assistant/fellow at a social science research institute.

Do you think I have a chance?

Answer (score 4):

It is true that in the Netherlands they prefer it if you have a masters. However, some people have been admitted and completed PhD programs without one. I am one of those people, and I had less industry experience than yourself.

I think your chances are good, and your CV sounds better than many people with a masters. But it will depend on your potential supervisors. You should contact prospective supervisors beforehand (this is what I did). Sometimes there are administrative issues, so the supervisors will have to explain to the graduate school in the university why they are hiring someone without a masters.

Comment: "Prefer" is kind of an understatement. It is literally written into the law that you must have a Masters to get a PhD, but there is a clause that in *exceptional circumstances* an exception can be made. A good amount of industry experience *could* be sufficient for that, but it's highly unusual and will be a lot of administrative work. [Artikel 7.18 Wet op het hoger onderwijs en wetenschappelijk onderzoek](http://wetten.overheid.nl/jci1.3:c:BWBR0005682&hoofdstuk=7&titeldeel=1&paragraaf=3&artikel=7.18&z=2018-02-01&g=2018-02-01)

Comment: "and will be a lot of administrative work." - this didn't seem to be the case when I started my PhD (2012).